# Clickonce update install prerequisite

Tags: clickonce

I have an application deployed using Clickonce to over 200 users, the application was initially developed and deployed with .NET 2.0.  I have to migrate it to .NET 4.5.2, I set the prerequisites to check for "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (x86 and x64)".  I'm trying to deploy it as an update (which it is) but when I tested in on PC without the 4.5.2 I'm getting this screen:

[image: System Update Required]

> Unable to install or run this application.
>   This application requires Version 4.5.2 Full or other compatible .NET Framework

If the user use the installation URL created by Clickonce it is running the .NET 4.5.2 installer.  Is there a way to make the update to launch the .NET installer automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this problem because I was browsing to the manifest file rather than setup.exe. Something to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

Open Publish tab from the project properties, then prerequisites, then select the middel option as in the next pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I downloaded the files and set to "Download prerequisites from same location"  and the clickonce created the folders with the files but it still showing the message when the pc doesn't have the 4.5.2.  As I said the brand new installation works, it install the .NET 4.5.2. The problem is when updating and the pc doesn't have the 4.5.2